# How can i print unhandled exception to the Console instead of the Browser in Django?

Tags: python, django

I got 500 errors in Django console but it doesn't print any information to the Console about the error.

How can i print the detail to Console ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run the server with `--traceback` option and set `DEBUG=False` in `settings.py`.

You will get the traceback on console.

Comment: Please don't approve [suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1128728) [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1128721). If needed, refer to [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157423/187824) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use [django-sentry](http://getsentry.com). This app can send tracebacks with local values etc ... and display it conveniently. So if a user finds a way to trigger an exception, you will be able to see it in your sentry and fix it more easily.